# Trying to write https://etherscan.io/writecontract/ transfer from

Tags: transferfrom

I transferred link tokens to xdai network using trust wallet. But trust wallet come to find out doesn’t allow users to switch to poa network xdai. So I need to write within the contract to transfer the tokens to my MetaMask wallet address. Clearly I’m a noob,but I got this far Didnt I?

Comment: Mind you, in all of this my trust wallet has been compromised but the thief hasn’t realized this transaction. So I have a chance at saving half of my original balance if successful!

Answer (score 0):

What's the link to your contract? What's the code?

You might be able to just write a small contract that .transfer({to: 'metamask wallet address'}, {from: 'yourxDAIaddresstrustwallet', amountToTransfer) or something similar.

You can use blockscout.com/ to find the contract on the xDAI network.

You can use remix.ethereum.org with your Metamask on the xDAI network and deploy a contract that transfers your $LINK to your Metamask account, but may need some xDAI in your Metamask account first. Remix will register it as a custom RPC network.

Setup your Metamask for xDAI by using the following config:
Select the network tab in your metamask. CustomRPC
Select ‘Custom RPC’
Enter in the following:

Network name: xDAI
New RPC URL: rpc.xdaichain.com/
Chain ID: 100
Symbol: xDAI
Block Explorer URL: https://blockscout.com/poa/xdai
Select the xDAI network in Metamask in the same dropdown.

Then go to remix.ethereum.org, select the 'injected web3' in the deploy and run tx's tab. You can - from here - deploy any contract on xDAI network.